# Which is better Entity Framework query with LINQ or without Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

There are two ways to fetch data form the database.

Query #1:

```
var Q = (from c in ctx.customers 
         where c.id = 10
         select new
                {
                     c.id,
                     c.Name,
                }).ToList();
```

Query #2:

```
var Q = (from c in ctx.customers
         select new 
                {
                    c.id,
                    c.Name,
                }).ToList().Where(x => x.id = 10);
```

I want to know which one is faster and better for many records. Please list some advantages and disadvantages of both too. There are other queries too that could be same like that.

Comment: You should read how LINQ works and why the second approach, for the simplest queries, is terrible

Comment: 1st will do the filter on the SQL server, 2nd will pull everything in to local memory, and filter it there.  You should *probably* prefer the 1st form.

Comment: The second way will get you an unecessary amount of data. It's the better way to filter as much on the SQL side as possible.

Comment: Technically all of that is Linq.  Also if you want to switch from `IQueryable` (that will be translated to SQL) and `IEnumerable` you can just use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` and avoid an intermediate list being created.  The only time you should do that is when you'r dealing with something that cannot be translated to SQL (and even then you should try at least get all filtering done in the `IQueryable` first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using in terms of syntax, both of them are the same.

If you are asking about the extra where clause in the second one, the first one is better and faster. Because it builds the whole query and then fires just one query to the database. But on the second one, as soon as you to the first ToList, it will fire a query to the database and get all records because the filter is applied after that.

LINQ usually builds your query and does not execute each statement in the database. It builds you query and returns an IQueryable. When you add conditions, sorting, select statements to the IQueryable, it will still return IQueryable. Which will not execute any query. Once you use methods which actually gets record from the DB, the Iqueryable that has been built as a result of all the statements finally gets executed and records returned from DB. ToLIst is one of such method which executes a query in DB. ToArray, First, Single are examples of some more which will actually execute a query to DB.